# How do I get rid of mud, vomit, blood and other contaminants?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Due to a slightly miscalculated water-feature, I have a muddy dining room. The dwarves don't seem overly bothered, but I can't help but feel that it's not doing the engravings justice.

How can I remove the mud from the floor of my dining room?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure there are dwarves with the cleaning labor enabled. They will only clean smoothed, engraved or built floors. Walls will be cleaned automagically if an adjacent floor tile is cleaned, but not otherwise. There is no way to tell dwarves to clean, so it is very much a waiting game.

If they are tracking the mud all over the place you may want to designate the muddy tiles as restricted traffic zones, to minimize its spread (This may be more valuable when dealing with pools of rectum-dissolving demon blood).

Flowing water can displace most contaminants, moving them out of the way, and pumping water purifies it. Admittedly, this is not going to do much to help with mud, which is made by water.

If the tile is made of natural stone, you can also construct a floor over it, getting a clean floor (Thanks to Stuart Pegg for testing).

Also, outside tiles may be cleaned of contaminants on season change (at least it did in earlier version), so you may wish to simply knock the roof through. The added benefit of having a sunlit dining room is that it will prevent cave adaptation (though, if they already have cave adaptation, it will cause them to drop barfs all over the place for a while, which may seem counterintuitive).

Comment: There is also an init option "Dwarves track spatter in fortress mode" that you should set to OFF if it isn't already.

Comment: Oh, i've had an idea. Can anybody test if constructing a floor over natural stone remove contaminants, and if constructing a floor over an engraving preserve the engraving?

Comment: Definite no to the latter. I'll have to test the former.

Comment: Great, I was just about to ask if this was fixed in the latest version, since I know that around Christmas dwarves never cleaned up blood.

Comment: Also, if I have an unsmoothed floor, can I smooth it so that the dwarves will clean it?

Comment: @kotekzot: I'm so so sure about the smoothing of muddy floor. It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @StuartPegg it doesn't? Well, that's embarrassing. Have you tried constucting a floor on top of mud?

Comment: @kotekzot: Excuse the delay: Yes, you can construct a floor on rough muddy stone, leaving clean smooth floor behind.

Comment: @StuartPegg cheers, added to the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that clean jobs are generated over carved stairs or for example a farm/soil? My farm, soil close to the farm and stairs carved in rock has been all covered in vomit / beast ichor for a few seasons already. It seems that smoothed rock get cleaned quite quickly, but not those I just mentioned (great answer BTW, this info isn't even in the DF wiki)

Comment: @KurzedMetal thanks! I would try replacing carved stairs with constructed ones, since you can't smooth them (make sure you have the necessary materials on the z-level where you intend to construct stairs or that there's an alternate route for your dwarves to take to other z-levels). Smoothing the floor/wall before carving stairs in it may possibly work, but that wouldn't help with existing stairs even if it did.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to 'cheaty' methods you can use DFHack which can clean the tiles with the cleanmap tool. I'm not sure if dwarfs with the cleaning labor ever clean muddy floors due to muddy floors generally being created by the player in order to farm.

Comment: Only constructed, smoothed and engraved floors will be cleaned.